# Fast way to find key-value pair in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite, csv, arraylist

Sounds pretty trivial but I really despair:

How do I import and match a value to a given key in an elegant fast way?

Just telephone area code - finding the matching prefix for a given zone (no multi-user). I have it as CSV but SQLite would be fine, too. SQLite connector? Or Dictionary? I don't know ...

Thank you in advance!

Nico

Comment: It depends ... leaving it in a CSV file, everytime you fire up your program you need to load and parse the CSV into some data structure you can work with. If that is not of concern that's OK, otherwise a database would be better. Also how fast does it need to be? 1ms? 10ms? 100ms? how big is your data set? what have you tried so far? what is the current time it takes?

Comment: Binary search list or tree, or perhaps a radix tree. Don't program it yourself, find a library that has one already

Comment: Thank you Tomek and Charlieface! Sorry, I forgot to mention. Only 5200 entries but low-endy target machine in the end. On my old 2nd gen mobile i7 recognition happens immediately this way so I have absolutely no worries anymore.
I post my snippet in a seperate comment because of the character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that. It's a console application.
Not pretty with the global creation and intialization but I didn't manage to do it across multiple source files by using only just a public class (type "Dictionary" and return this).

Main .cs file:

```
static class GlobalVar
{ 
    public static Dictionary<string, string> areaCodesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Second .cs file:

```
public class AreaCodes
{
    public static void ParseCsv()
    {
        var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["areaCodesCsv"];

        using (var strReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (!strReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = strReader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null) { continue; }

                var csv = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["areaCodesCsvDelim"]));

                // areaCodesDict.Add(key, value)
                GlobalVar.areaCodesDict.Add(csv[0], csv[1]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Example usage in Main.cs file again:

```
        if (regexMatch.Success)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in GlobalVar.areaCodesDict)
            { 
                if(destNumber.StartsWith(pair.Value))
                {
                    destNumber = destNumber.Replace(pair.Value, pair.Key);
                }
            }
        }
```